# Assigning container width and Height to Iframe in jspx for IE browser

Tags: javascript, html, css, iframe, oracle-adf

I have an inline frame ,which displays CAD/CAM images in JPSX page.I'm setting the height and width of the inline frame to that of the container by using Java script.
The height and width are being successfully set in Chrome /safari and Firefox ,only in case of IE the content is being cut of both in terms of height and width.
Can anyone suggest me any Css to fix it so that the inline frame fits in container.

Following is the JS that i'm using to set height and width:
    var $iframe = evt.GetSourceDomElement();
    var $wrapper = $iframe.parentElement;
    var width = $wrapper.offsetWidth - 5;
    $iframe.width = (width) + "px";
    var height = $wrapper.offsetHeight - 5;
    $iframe.height = (height) + "px";